# Make a "Load More" button that shows 2 more articles on my blog

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-selectors

I want to make a button or link, that, when clicked will display the next two div (articles) that I have stored in the index. Kind of like the infinite scroll tumblr effect. This as close as I could get. Either doesn't display any of the divs, or displays all of them.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="post.html">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        Title
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        Description
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Trevor Healy</a> on September 24, 2014</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="post.html">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        Title
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        Description
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Trevor Healy</a> on September 18, 2014</p>
            </div>
 <!-- Pager -->
            <ul class="pager">
                <li class="next">
                    <a href="#" id="load">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


            <hr>
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="post.html">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        Title
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        Description
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Trevor Healy</a> on August 24, 2014</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="post.html">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        Title
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        Description
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Trevor Healy</a> on July 8, 2014</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a css file that stores:

```
.post-preview { display:none; }
```

and this is the script that I run on the page:

```
    <script>
$(function(){
    $(".post-preview").slice(0, 2).show(); // select the first two
    $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".post-preview:hidden").slice(0, 2).show(); // select next two hidden divs and show them

    });
});

 </script>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at JSFiddle?

Comment: sure: https://jsfiddle.net/tr0qoo3t/

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like the fiddle is empty.

Comment: still learning: https://jsfiddle.net/uzy14zLb/

Comment: Look. It works: https://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/uzy14zLb/1/. You just didn't include `jQuery` into your Fiddle. Check if you have `$ is not defined` in your browser console - it means that jQuery library is not included.

Comment: what is best practice for including jQuery into my file?

Comment: There is no "bad practice" or "good practice". You simply need to add `<script>` refering to jQuery into your HTML. Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

the content is correct - the JQuery library was not loaded.